# Taking char and integer with Scanf

Tags: c

In the console

when user writes "S 4" it must 4x4 square appear

when "R 4 6" ==> 4x6 rectangle

when "T D 4" ==> rectangle right aligned

when "T U 4" ===> x-axis reflected triangle

How can i do it with scanf format?
Shapes are simple but i couldnt do the scanf part

It is exactly what i want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7R0I.jpg

Entire of my code:
Actually in the switch part, TU,TD is not accepted

```
int main() {
printf("Enter a valid type\n ");
char shape;
int row,col,i,j;
do{
scanf(" %c %c %c",&shape,&row,&col);
switch(shape){
case 'R':
    for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(j=0; j<col; j++){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }break;
case 'S':
    for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(j=0; j<row; j++){
                printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }break;
case "TU":
    for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(j=0; j<row; j++){
            if(i+j==row)
                printf("*");    
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }break;
case "TD":
    for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(j=0; j<row; j++){
            if(i+j!=row)
                printf("*");    
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }break; 

        }
 }while(shape!='E');
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked up the documentation of the function? Did you look for example code to get an idea of the usage? What have you tried so far to solve your problem on your own?

Comment: @moooeeeep Actually i think something with if,else format but i think this is a long way. I'm searching for shortcut.

Comment: In C usually there are no shortcuts. Show us where you got stuck at implementing this. [Post code.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22754/179891)

Comment: @moooeeeep I add but as i sad it is stupid idea

Comment: Read [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and pay attention to the result (number of scanned items)

Comment: For the sake of this question, please try to write another program that does nothing but to read a character and a number, and print them afterwards. Try to avoid ternary operators. Post the entire code (shouldn't be much more than about 10 lines or so).

Comment: @moooeeeep i add, please help me because this assignment must be uploaded until midnight and actually i have already have another assignment too. :(

Comment: @user2971559 Which timezone are you in? (not that I really care)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use one `scanf` line to input all of the command, because different commands have different formats. Do either of the following:

- Read a line of text; try to parse it multiple times (I prefer this one)
- Read the first character; depending of its value read the rest of the command

To implement the first one, you can use the return value of `scanf`, as multiple people suggested. If `scanf` succeeds, it returns a known number (check the documentation for details). If it fails, you can try again *with the same input* and a different format string.

```
char command[80]; // let's hope no one tries to input more than 78 characters...
...
fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);
if (sscanf(command, " S %d", &size) == 1) // try to read a command starting with "S"
{
    // whatever
}
else if (sscanf(command, " R %d %d", &row, &col) == 2) // try to read a command starting with "R"
{
    // whatever else
}
else
...
```

I am not sure you understand or are allowed to use `fgets` and `sscanf`, therefore you can use the other method:

```
scanf(" %c", &shape); // read just the shape type
switch (shape)
{
case 'T': // triangle? which one?
    scanf(" %c", &dir); // read the direction of the triangle
    switch (dir)
    {
    case 'U':
        scanf("%d", &size); // read just the size of the triangle
        ... // do your stuff
    }
case 'S': // whatever
}
```

The structure of the code becomes a bit messy, but maybe you will prefer this one...